# Please solve this syllogism.

Tags: logic

This is a question from syllogisms, for which the statements are

> **1) Some Pencils are Pens
>   2) No Pen is an Eraser 
>   3) All Sharpeners are Erasers**

And the Conclusions are

> **1) No Eraser is a Pencil
>   2) All Pencils can never be Sharpeners**

Which of the conclusions follow according to the statements?

I would say that first conclusion doesn't follow but I am stuck with second conclusion, since I couldn't understand the meaning of that conclusion properly.

It seems that the meaning of second conclusion is ambiguous. But I'm not sure of it. Could you please explain this to me.

Comment: Did you consider using a Venn diagram?

Comment: @abiessu yes, I did using Venn diagram.

Comment: What does the diagram look like for the first three statements?  If I read them correctly, I think both conclusions are false...

Comment: @abiessu I think so. If the conclusion means that No Pencil is a Sharpener, then both are falls but I'm not sure of it's meaning. I was wondering, if it could mean Some P are Sharpeners. Could you clarify this?

Comment: Sorry, it's not falls, It's false. It's a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to solve such questions is to either prove the validity of the conclusion or to show that there is a model of the given premises (situation that satisfies them) that does not satisfy the conclusion.

Consider the situation where there are two objects A,B. A is a pencil and a pen but neither an eraser nor sharpener. B is not a pen but is a pencil and an erase and a sharpener! It so happens that this single model already fails to satisfy both conclusions at one go. In general you might need to come up with a different situation to invalidate each conclusion.

Comment: Yes..I did the same way. But one question if I were given two conclusions as All Sharpeners are pencils and All Sharpeners can be pencils, I would thought that both are different. Here former one doesn't follow but Latter one follows. Am I right? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @GaneshReddy: If you want to incorporate modal verbs like "can", you will have to use something more than classical logic, such as modal logic. Basically every statement is taken to mean something about the current world, and "possibly P" translates to "in some world P holds", while "necessarily P" translates to "in every world P holds". "never P" translates to "necessarily not P". Note that "P implies ( possibly P )" and "( never P ) implies not P", and so if we can show that some world satisfies P, then "never P" can't be valid. See http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-modal/ for more.

Comment: @GaneshReddy: If this question is from an undergraduate course, it is highly likely that modals are to be ignored when translating to (classical) logic.

Comment: Thanks for providing the link. So, I think here the second conclusion in my above comment related to modal logic . Can I say it's valid(possibiliy).

Comment: @GaneshReddy: I'll interpret your "All sharpeners can be pencils" as "Possibly all sharpeners are pencils". Yes it is true in the usual modal logic, because there is a world with no sharpeners. Note that we can't translate directly to "Every sharpener possibly is a pencil", because a sharpener in the current world may not exist in another world, so it is not well-defined to ask whether it is possibly a pencil. It would depend on your rules for the modal logic.

Comment: If you don't mind could you explain that using Venn diagram, if you can. I think I need to edit the question, right?

Comment: @GaneshReddy: Venn diagrams are useless for modal logic. As I said, if this is an undergraduate problem, **ignore** all modals!

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your response to my every comment. It's a question given in a competitive exam, which I found on a local forum. I think you're right.

Comment: @GaneshReddy: Okay since it's from a contest it's likely that the setter did not intend any modal meaning to it. Note that interestingly, in the US the sentence "All pencils are not sharpeners." is interpreted by a large fraction of the population to actually mean "Not all pencils are sharpeners."!!! This is severely contrary to logical interpretation, but it's just how it is in the US (same with double negation). The problem setter might very well have attempted to forbid that interpretation by using "can never be", but ended up unintentionally causing you to suspect a modal meaning...

Comment: Exactly, that's where I confused again when a few people said it's modal logic(because of "Can"). Your explanations are really helpful. Thank you very much.

Comment: @GaneshReddy: You're welcome! To accept an answer that you are satisfied with, click the green tick next to it. =)

Comment: @GaneshReddy: Oh that... Please feel free to wait for more answers, but see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2553/21820. In my view no waiting is necessary as long as the answer really is complete and the asker understand it completely, but if not then not accepting any at all is perfectly acceptable. =)

Comment: Please clear this doubt. If the _statement_ is given as **All A are B** and _conclusion_ is given same as the Statement(**All A are B**). Does it follow or not? Please answer this.

Comment: @Learner: Yes, from A you can always deduce A. But you shouldn't use comments on a post to ask questions unrelated to it. If you don't want to ask a new question, feel free to ask at http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44058/logic and ping me there.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct to read the second conclusion as "No pencil is a sharpener" and you do not have the data to prove that.  In a two part question you don't have to have one valid and one not.

Comment: But a few friends of mine are arguing with me that it's a case of possibility, which is not a case here. Am I right?

Comment: @GaneshReddy: You are right, and see my answer for how to **justify** that the argument is invalid. *Ross*' answer is correct but does not give justification for why "you do not have the data to prove that".